# Workflow SharePoint 2010

Tags: workflow, email

I am extremely new at SharePoint Designer. That being said, I need to set up a work flow to send an email to when a data is added to a field in a list. The email address would come from another list on the same page. We have a program where you choose the office and plant to send issues. Both are drop down and are in a list with an assigned email address. I did not create this. When the office creates the original issue for the plant an email is sent to the plant. There is a response item in the list. My manager would like a email sent back to the office when the plant enters a response. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried to created the workflow and have been unsuccessful.

This is the work flow [image][image]

The emails addresses would not go in the list without hyperlink. But the work flow is Lookup as text.

Comment: So there is already a workflow emailing the plant when the issue is created? And the email addresses are kept in a separate list?

Comment: Yes. There is also a different list for the plant to email the office when there is a problem with what the office send to the plant. So there are 3 list, one for offices, one for plant and a list of email addresses they both use.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use a Lookup instead of a choice dropdown to get email addresses of offices. Then you can include the email address from the email list in the settings for the office lookup field.

[image: Lookup field settings]

Then in your workflow, use the `Wait for field to change` action to wait for your Response field: 
`Wait for Response to not equal Current Item:Response`.

Then send your email with the `Send Email` action, with the "To" address being `Current Item:Office:Email` as Lookup Value (as Text)

Comment: I am going to try that now. Our system deleted your picture so I sent it to my self to see what it was.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I am going to try again, maybe I am missing something because the second time I tried I didn't get the option to have the lookup value as a text. The field for the email addresses is a email address which shows as mailto: then the email address. So should it be a text field?

Comment: Do you mean that the email address in the lookup list is a hyperlink field?

Comment: A hyperlink field won't be available as part of a lookup field. You'd have to use text.

Comment: Yes it is a hyper link. Is there a way to make it work with a hyperlink? Other wise how would it know which email address to send the message to?

Comment: No, it can't be a hyperlink.  You would just enter the email address as text.

Comment: Because I don't want to change the email addresses hyperlink list, I created a new one called Office List. I entered the email addresses as text in a column called email text. The title column had the corresponding name. When I created the lookup item, it would not let me choose Email Text as one of the choices. All I had was Title. I chose that which did have the office names listed. When I tried to create the work flow it would not let me choose Email Text as Text. It made it a script file. Is the fact I have the email addresses as text in a separate list causing the issue?

Comment: Is `Email Text` selected in the column settings under "Add a column to show each of these additional fields?"

Comment: I don't see the exact same wording. But the column is listed in the allitems view. There are only 2 columns. List is called Office List and 2 columns are Title and Email Text. Both are in the default view. I do appreciate your help. I know how hard it is to try and help someone when you can see what they are doing or talk to them.

Comment: I think I mean the other list... the one where you're using the Office list as a lookup field.  In the settings for that lookup column, do you see the "add a column..." option?

Comment: I wish I could put a screen shot here. I did have add columns but the Email Text column is not list. I am going to delete it and start over. And will see what happens then. :-)

Comment: Ok. And if you do need to add a screenshot, you can edit your original post.

Comment: I added the workflow and a picture of the list. Guess I am in over my head.

Comment: These are the columns. Have to add in more than one comment.

Comment: CS Office:  Choice Item  Email Repsonse to Office  Lookup Item Email Repsonse to Office:Response Email Office (linked to item)  Lookup  
EmailClass  Multiple lines of text Item  EmailContainer  Multiple lines of text Item  EmailShape  Multiple lines of text Item  ExpireDate  Calculated (calculation based on other columns)  Item  
Impact on Delivery Unit:  Multiple lines of text Item  
Mail Class:  Choice Item

Comment: Mail Container:  Choice Item  Mail Shape:  Choice Item  MAQ Date:  Date and Time Item  MPOO  Single line of text Item  Plant:  Choice Item  Quality Concern:  Multiple lines of text Item  
Response:  Multiple lines of text Item

Comment: So I think you'd want the "To" of your email to go to `Current Item: Office:Response Email Office` return field as `Lookup value (as text)`